# 8 Puzzle game scramble method

Tags: java, user-interface, puzzle

I did a 8-puzzle game. I found my scramble method has some problem, but I don't know how to fix it.
Is there anyone can help my code? Here is the scramble method code. my code problem is, after I clicked the scramble button, the number will only two numbers pictures, then click scramble again, it only show one number in 9 buttons.

```
public void scramble()
{
     for(int i = 0; i <SHUFFLE_NUM; i++)
    {
        int x1 = rand.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);
        int x2 = rand.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);
        int y1 = rand.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);
        int y2 = rand.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);

        Piece temp = board[x1][y1];
        board [x1][y1] = board[x2][y2];
        board[x1][y2] = temp;
    }
}
```

***update***

here i find another bug, after i click the reset button, when i try to move my number button, the move step is wrong. here i attach my move method and reset method

```
public boolean move(int _x, int _y)
    {

    boolean valid = false;

    if(_x == currentCol-1 && _y == currentRow ) // on the left of empty one
        valid = true;

    else if(_x == currentCol+1&&_y == currentRow) //on the right of empty one
        valid = true;

    else if(_x == currentCol&&_y == currentRow-1) // on the top of empty one
        valid = true;

    else if(_x == currentCol &&_y == currentRow +1) // on the bottom of empty one
        valid = true; 

    if(valid)
    {
        Piece temp;
        temp = board[_x][_y];
        board[_x][_y] = board[currentCol][currentRow];
        board[currentCol][currentRow] = temp;

        currentCol = _x;
        currentRow = _y;
    }

    return valid;

}
```

here is reset method

```
public void reset()
    {

    for(int i =0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++)
      for(int j =0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++)
      {
          int value = i*BOARD_SIZE+j+1 ;
            String filePath;
            if(value!= BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE)
                filePath = "Piece" + value +".jpg"; //what is this mean?
            else
                filePath = "blank piece.jpg";
            board[i][j]= new Piece(new ImageIcon(filePath),i, j, value);

      }

}
```

move is work correct if i didn't not click the reset button..

Comment: "the number will only two numbers pictures" what does that mean?

Comment: Once you have fixed this (copy-paste error), consider that your scrambled board may not be solvable.  See "parity of a permutation" under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle#Solvability

Comment: Regarding your update: have you tried to do the debugging yourself?  SO is NOT a community to provide free debugging service. You don't even give useful information on what do you mean by "Wrong".

Answer (score 5):

Though I believe the answer is obvious, I don't really want to tell you.

Instead, I suggest you to learn how to debug.

Have a modern IDE like Eclipse, either have a unit test or a little application., and turn on debug mode, and run your code.

Add a break point inside the for loop, step through it, and inspect the changes of the variables and `board`.  You will know the answer easily.

Answer (score 3):

```
 board[x1][y2] = temp;
```

Shouldn't this be

```
 board[x2][y2] = temp;
```

**Update**

After you call your `reset()` method, your `currentCol` and `currentRow` variables will be wrong; you need to update them to point at the newly empty piece. Add this before exiting the method :

```
currentCol = BOARD_SIZE - 1;
currentRow = BOARD_SIZE - 1;
```

Comment: thank you ! would you mind read my update, i found another bug in my code

Answer (score 2):

Your swap code is little wrong...

```
Piece temp = board[x1][y1];
board [x1][y1] = board[x2][y2];
board[x1][y2] = temp; // You're mapping the wrong x position here
```

It should read

```
Piece temp = board[x1][y1];
board [x1][y1] = board[x2][y2];
board[x2][y2] = temp;
```

Comment: thank you! i found another bug in my code would you mind read my update?

Comment: You could try resting the `currentCol` and `currentRow` variables to something like -1 or 0, it's difficult to say from the example code. Best bet is to walk through the code with a debugger and inspect the state of the variables

Comment: the move is only work wrong after i clicked the reset button..otherwise is correct

Comment: Soo, try resting the `currentCol` and `currentRow` variables in the rest method

Comment: you mean reset the currentCol and currenRow?